# How to generate an HTML report from PartCover results .xml

Tags: code-coverage, partcover

How to generate an HTML report from PartCover results .xml

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate what you mean by PartCover results .xml.

If you want to generate a HTML report from a XML in the general sense, you can do so using XSLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool you can use to generate a HTML report:

https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator

Here you can find an article how to integrate the tool into MSBuild:

http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2009/10/30/msbuild-code-coverage-analysis-with-partcover-and-reportgenerator

Comment: ReportGenerator has been improved over the last months. It is **much** faster now. The latest release uses TPL for even better performance. Download: http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no convenient tool like NCoverExplorer that can transform a PartCover results .xml file into a .html report, but there are some .xsl files that can be used to transform PartCover's results to .html in CruiseControl.NET: [Using CruiseControl.NET with PartCover](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+PartCover).

You could take those .xsl files from CruiseControl.NET and convert your PartCover results.xml using something like [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle)'s XslTransform.exe.

By the way, if this happens to be related to TeamCity, the upcoming 5.0 release will include support for .NET coverage using PartCover or NCover. See the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD5/.NET+Code+Coverage) for more informations. Otherwise ignore this paragraph ;-)

Comment: Oh wait, I know that name. You're one of the TeamCity developers! In that case, ignore my last paragraph. It's a small world after all :)

Comment: LoL dude, the last paragraph is funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is probably to use msxsl, a simple command line transformer. I use it for exactly this purpose, and it's easy to integrate into your build system.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2FB55371-C94E-4373-B0E9-DB4816552E41&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a complicated way of doing it, but I did this with the Simian xml report. Created an XSL file for the formatting, then wrote a dumb little console application;

```
private const string MissingExtension = "Please enter a valid {0} file, this is missing the extension.";
    private const string InvalidExtension = "Please enter a valid {0} file, the file provided has an invalid extension.";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a xsl file and xml file full path.");
            return;
        }

        var xslFile = args[0];
        var xmlFile = args[1];

        if (!CheckFileNameFormat(xslFile, false))
            return;
        if (!CheckFileNameFormat(xmlFile, true))
            return;

        var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        // Load the XSL stylesheet.
        transform.Load(xslFile);
        // Transform xml file into an html using the xsl file provided.
        transform.Transform(xmlFile, xmlFile.Replace("xml", "html"));
    }

    private static bool CheckFileNameFormat(string fileName, bool isXmlFile)
    {
        var extension = isXmlFile ? "xml" : "xsl";

        // valida that the argument has a period
        if (fileName.IndexOf(".") < 1)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format(MissingExtension, extension));
            return false;
        }

        var filePieces = fileName.Split('.');
        // split on the period and make sure the extension is valid
        if (filePieces[filePieces.GetUpperBound(0)] != extension)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format(InvalidExtension, extension));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then I can call it from a MSBuild file like so;

```
 <Target Name="RunSimian" DependsOnTargets="RebuildSolution">

<Exec IgnoreExitCode="true" Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Build\Packages\Simian\simian-2.2.24.exe&quot; -formatter=xml:$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Build\Artifacts\simian.xml -language=cs -excludes=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Product\Production\**\*.Designer.cs $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Production\**\*.cs" >
</Exec>

<Exec IgnoreExitCode="true" Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Build\Packages\XmlToHtmlConverter.exe&quot; $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Build\Packages\Simian\simian.xsl $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Build\Artifacts\simian.xml">
</Exec>
```